# prevent user from executing a certain command from within a certain directory in unix

Tags: linux, unix, command, blacklist

How can I prevent a user (or me) from typing a command when I am currently in a special directory?

For example: There is a user who often uses git wrong. When he is in the directory /path/to/our/repo he should not be able to type `git merge`

Another example: I'm a beginner in using CMake and I am often using it very wrong so that I need help from someone after I destroyed everything again. Let's say I don't want to allow me to execute `cmake .` from within /not/in/your/src/folder .

Is there something like a "blacklist" of commands? i.e. a list that specifies that user U cannot execute command C from within directory d.

And if not, how can I create it?

Comment: You might want a git hook that verifies the state of the repo before allowing a commit.  For example, if the working copy contains a merge, disallow.  The user can still convert it to a rebase, and after doing it a few times the wrong way and having to redo it, he or she will learn to be more careful.

Comment: The solution should not be for git only. This was only an example. I was looking for restriction for any command.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some restricted shell like [rbash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html) (and make that the login shell of your user).

You could wrap the `git` command into a script or a shell function (of the same name) to add checks....

However, I believe it might be more a social issue than a technical one: educate your user to correctly run `git` (perhaps by showing him some GUI tool, or how to use `git` under emacs, etc...)

Comment: but the user is going to learn it this way. It is a not so painful way of learning - for all of us. Thank you for your answer, I'm going to check that.